# Looking for dystopian sci fi/horror web story set during a war (religious, possibly), where one side has giant flying alien 'angels' helping them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, scp-foundation

I'm not sure if anyone can help me out, but I'm trying to remember a sci fi story I read online a couple of years ago. I can't remember where I found it (I thought it was from reading comments on an [SCP](http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-093), but I haven't been able to find it there). Anyway, I remember that it was a pretty well-known web original story (with many chapters), so perhaps someone here will have heard of it...

It was set in a dystopian/post-apocalyptic world where there's a war raging between two sides of humanity, one of which has giant flying monsters/aliens (I think they're referred to as 'angels', or they've been given the names of biblical angels perhaps) assisting them. I remember a scene where one or two of these angels are summoned to a battle taking place in the distance, and the main characters sees them fly overhead. There's been some kind of alien invasion (I think), most towns are deserted, and at several points the story flashes back to when the main character was a kid, and he encountered one of the creatures in his neighbour's yard, and it tried to control his mind... or something. I realise this is really vague - I mainly remember the monstrous alien 'angels' - one of which the rebels had managed to capture in some kind of facility (which is where the finale takes place - the main character having a psychic battle with this alien/angel). It's so frustrating not being able to remember any specific character names etc, as my google searches have unsurprisingly proved futile so far! As I said, I remember it being pretty well known (many of the commenters on the forum I found it on originally seemed to have read it before), so if any of the above snippets are ringing a bell with anyone, I'd be grateful if you could refresh my memory!!

Comment: Is it possible its neon genesis evangelion fan fiction at all?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not it. It was definitely an original story rather than fan fiction.

Comment: The SCP story you mentioned is here
http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-093

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is seven years late (and quite possibly wrong), but it sounds like a match for [*That Insidious Beast*](https://www.somethingawful.com/series/that-insidious-beast/) by Zack Parsons. This is a series of short stories published on SomethingAwful.com in 2008 and 2009.

The series is set on Earth in an alternative present, and describes a dystopian war between two groups of lovecraftian alien entities known as 'Angels' and 'Unfolders'. Both sides have recruited human nations as proxies, and the war causes huge damage and massive casualties. The United States is on the side of the Angels, and appears to have become a theocratic dictatorship.

Most of the OPs recollections seem to come from the final three stories in the series ([Fall Sweeps](https://www.somethingawful.com/news/insidious-fall-sweeps/1/), [Delta Frame](https://www.somethingawful.com/news/insidious-delta-frame/1/) and [Master Copy](https://www.somethingawful.com/news/insidious-beast-final/1/)). These form a single story arc, unlike the earlier stories, which have self-contained plots.

The main character of this final story arc is a soldier in the US Army, and fights alongside Angels, who have been given Biblical-sounding codenames.

> I read the orders. Full corps and reserves committed for Operation Persephone Gray. "Strategic assistance will be provided by The Host."
>
> None of us needed confirmation, but there it was. Angels.
>
> We could feel it in the air the night before. Feel them, I mean. Five of them come up from Oklahoma and Tennessee. They had fancy codenames. Conjurer, Revenant, Archangel, Weeping Maiden, and Hierophant.
>
> <sub>[*That Insidious Beast*: Fall Sweeps](https://www.somethingawful.com/news/insidious-fall-sweeps/3/)</sub>

The main character also recalls a childhood incident where he encountered an Unfolder in a neighbour's yard.

> I run barefoot all the way back to my house. My skin is clammy and covered in goose pimples. I saw it. God above, I saw it. Every awful detail.
>
> I bang in through the back door. My mom is cooking chili on the stove. She is startled. I am breathless from running all the way.
>
> It comes out in gasps. It's there! There in the back of Mrs. Harding's house! Beside her garden. Playing with-
>
> My mom realizes the magnitude of my claim. She snatches up the phone and calls the wardens.
>
> <sub>[*That Insidious Beast*: Fall Sweeps](https://www.somethingawful.com/news/insidious-fall-sweeps/4/)</sub>

The OPs recollection of the main character encountering an angel in some kind of facility is a partial match for an incident in the second-last story. Rather than a rebel base, this is a US Army facility and the main character has been summoned to communicate with an Angel known as the 'Hierophant'

> The tunnel is wide enough for a truck. It stinks of cattle and a crisp electric smell, like a fire in an outlet. The white tiles are floor-to-ceiling, glistening and polished. The dozens of broadcast towers above are the only thing that can deaden the tone. It's not enough. Not this close to the beast.
>
> [...]
>
> I wonder what this angel will look like, what his face will tell me. They are all different, or so they say. The church raves about their beauty and perfection, but the things glimpsed on the horizon at Pleasant Plain were anything but beautiful.
>
> <sub>[*That Insidious Beast*: Delta Frame](https://www.somethingawful.com/news/insidious-delta-frame/15/)</sub>

More details can be found on the [TVTropes page for the series](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WebOriginal/ThatInsidiousBeast).

Comment: OMG!! THANK YOU!!!! Yes I'm certain this is it! It's been bugging me for so long, and I'd just about given up hope of finding it again. I've revisited this page many times over the years - but didn't expect to receive an answer at this point. Thank you SO much - you've really made my day! I'm going to go and reread it now...!

Comment: @Jigowat, glad to help! Hope you enjoy the stories, they've certainly stayed with me - although apparently I'm the only person on this site that read them 

Answer (score 5):

It could be [*Lord Blackwood in the Land of the Unclean*](http://www.scp-wiki.net/lord-blackwood-and-the-land-of-the-unclean).

Matches the post apocalyptic setting, the flying monsters (the titular Unclean) and the militaristic elements.

> The Third Testament appears to have been written in the seventeenth century; and as I had not the time or inclination to read it in full, I referred to a history book about what is referred to in this world as the Second Coming. Prior to the year 1621 or so, I found, the history of this world had been much like our own aside from certain linguistic and cultural details, and an indication that the wide-spread colonization of the Americas had begun several hundred years earlier. In that year, the being called Him made itself known to the people of the world, and nations worldwide proclaimed it to be their God. He provided them with great advances in technology and medicine, which were the impetus of the advanced civilization I now beheld; but war broke out across the world over the question of which nations were most worthy of His love. When He beheld the devastation that His children had wrought, He wept - and where His tears fell, those who tasted of them were purified of sin and lost their inclination to fight. But those who refused to cease in strife, those who were consumed by sin and evil, their wickedness was magnified in His absence and took form until it became the Unclean, the giant abominations that to this day lurk in the Unfertile Lands. All life that the Unclean encounter is destroyed utterly - men and women, animals, even plants, are all consumed by the creatures and vanish into thin air, leaving behind only the ichor of sin it discharges when it feeds. Agents of the church known as the Blessed Militia guard these lands, and do constant battle to keep the Unclean imprisoned within.

....

> The beings called Unclean are not devils or beings of pure sin, but gross mutations of the human form itself. The key is the Tears. I know not what the true origin of that compound is or from whence it comes, but it is more than a simple tool of mind control. When human flesh is exposed to a significant enough concentration, it changes - the bonds that hold the atoms together peel away, and it becomes mutable and elastic, folding around and absorbing all other life introduced to it. A single mutant becomes two, and then three, and four, growing larger and larger, becoming less and less human in form, until it becomes Unclean.
>
> I wondered how these creatures first came to be created. Did the church fathers make weapons of them, to unleash upon those renegade nations that refused to submit to their will? Perhaps they use them for that reason still - I had found numerous reports in the history books of cities and country-sides being attacked by Unclean, suddenly loosed from their Unfertile Lands, whenever sentiment in that land had turned against the church. Even now they continued to throw millions of people into the Tears every year to better control them - some of them surely mutating as the result and becoming the basis of a new abomination. No wonder there were railways leading into the Unfertile Zones - it was necessary to dispose of the persons so changed. I wondered how many were sacrificed intentionally to make the Unclean more powerful and more menacing as weapons of terror.

By the way, the other Blackwood tales are a pretty good read too.